# How the contents of the DESCRIPTION.rst in python wheel are generated?

Tags: python, python-wheel

When I generate wheel for my python package with command `python setup.py bdist_wheel` I get a whl file DESCRIPTION.rst with only UNKNOWN string inside. How can I fill DESCRIPTION.rst with information that I want to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DESCRIPTION.rst` contains whatever you passed to the `long_description` argument of `setup()` in your `setup.py`.  This argument is intended to be used for supplying your package's README, and most packages set it with the equivalent of `long_description=open('README.rst').read()`.